# Check class inside button if it pass validation swap it with anohter class on the same button somehow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello i'm at coding a multi step form and have a question is it possible somehow in jquery or javascript to do this for example :

```
If ( this class right eg "class=submit" than active or supersedes it with this class"class=next action-button") ? the same button
```

Button code that need to transform from this

`<button type="submit" class="button"  id="button1" >Submit</button>`

TO

```
<button type="submit" class="next action-button" id="button1" >Submit</button>
```

viz to swap the `class="button"` with `class="next action-button"` if it pass the validation

Any idea. thanks in advance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery's `hasClass()` method](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) to check if your element has the class "submit":

```
var elem = $('#button1');

if (elem.hasClass('submit'))
    elem.removeClass('submit').addClass('next action-button');
```